# Microsoft Teams doesn't respect monitor position on restoring from the taskbar

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11, microsoft-teams

I have two monitors and some programs I like to keep on the second monitor.
So far every program respected their current monitor position, but Teams suddenly keep popping up on the primary monitor when I try to restore it from its minimized position.

[image]

How should I force it to remain on its respective monitor?

**UPDATE**:

When I change its maximized state to normal on the second monitor, *the taskbar icon is shown on the primary monitor while the window is on the second monitor*...so somehow Teams convinces Windows that it has an offset enough to be on the second monitor but it is actually on the first one. Seems like some really buggy behavior.

**UPDATE 2:**

Half a year later, Teams is still the only Microsoft-created software that violates the paradigms of Microsoft-created Windows.

Is the creator always above the rules? :)

**UPDATE 3:**

I went a little deeper and checked what's the difference between the respective client area coordinates of the window of a normally restored program (like Firefox web browser) and a messed up program (Teams).

The coordinates show 3 states: **visible, hidden, restored**.

Firefox (restore working on the second monitor):
[image]

Teams (restore *not working* on the second monitor):

[image]

It clearly looks that the framework behind Teams (possibly Electron) is based on some Direct3D rendering and the developers failed to save the coordinates when minimized so Windows could not restore it to its original position hence the (0,0) default coordinates. Possible solutions could be some registry change detection and saving the coordinates instead of the Teams program. Poor design, hopefully the new PWA application will be saved (hint: not working in One Outlook PWA either )

Comment: Works ok for me.  Have you tried restarting Teams?

Comment: @squillman Yes, restarted the computer, reinstalled Teams, yet it somehow fails. Every other program works... so embarassing

Comment: Try in *Settings > Personalisation > Taskbar* to turn off "Show taskbar on all displays".

Comment: @harrymc How will it help to make Teams remain on the second monitor if I turn off the taskbar for the second monitor?

Comment: If I advised this, it's because some poster claimed it solved his same problem.

Comment: So you advised to turn it off and then back on?

Comment: Unfortunately, turning off the taskbar and enabling again did not help.